# Como puedo hacer un menu sobre una imagen?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, sass

Espero y me puedan ayudar con una duda que tengo ya que desconozco mucho sobre css todavía.
Bueno, como puedo hacer un menu sobre una imagen con css ejemplo tengo el siguiente código html y css:

```
<div class="image-menu">
    <img src="images/img-bg.jpg" alt="test">
    <ul class="text-menu">
        <li>TITULO 1</li>
        <li>TITULO 2</li>
        <li>TITULO 3</li>
        <li>TITULO 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

.image-menu{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

.text-menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    font: bold 40px/40px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 0 0 10% 10%;
}
```

Pero no me sale como quiero, dejo una imagen de como pienso que debería quedar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El truco está en usar pixels y definir los margenes y rellenos deseados (además de sacarle el estilo lista) al elemento `UL`. en este ejemplo el `left` y `bottom` los puse en pixels, los podes usar en % pero por lo general tenes mas control al usar pixels ( los dispositivos retina o con diferentes pixel ratio hacen la cuenta de donde debería caer el asunto).

```css
.image-menu{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
    overflow:auto;
}

.text-menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    color: white;
    font: bold 40px/40px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
}
.text-menu LI {
text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-menu">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/480/?random" alt="test">
    <ul class="text-menu">
        <li>TITULO 1</li>
        <li>TITULO 2</li>
        <li>TITULO 3</li>
        <li>TITULO 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar los problemas que te pueda dar usar absolute, puedes poner la imagen como fondo del div, aquí tienes un ejemplo de como hacerlo, puedes conseguir el efecto que quieres con un diseño responsive.

```css
    .image-menu {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/480/?random);
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .text-menu {
        list-style:none;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 10%;
        left: 0;
        color: white;
        font: bold 40px/40px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        padding: 0 0 10% 10%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="image-menu">
        <ul class="text-menu">
            <li>TITULO 1</li>
            <li>TITULO 2</li>
            <li>TITULO 3</li>
            <li>TITULO 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: la imagen estaba siendo llamada por http (la página es https así que no la carga por considerarla insegura) le puse el mismo origen de mi ejemplo

Comment: Ni me había fijado, gracias por avisarme.